# Is it possible without disconnecting x-lite after first call and next call should go automatically?

Tags: asterisk

I have 4 numbers which are in folder (let say testFolder).(See customers name along with their number below):

[image]

Now i will start calling on testFolder. It will ring on my extension (extension is configured on x-lite) first and after picking the call from my x-lite, call will go to the John. Now as soon as John hangs up the call, my x-lite is also disconnect. And next call is again originating from my x-lite i.e x-lite is again ring and after picking the call, call will go to Nic's phone number.
Here I want that once the call originates from my x-lite, call will never hangup until i am not disconnecting the call from my end and if John hangs up the call, next call for Nic will automatically ring without disconnecting my x-lite.

> In summary, is it possible without disconnecting x-lite after first
>   call and next call should go automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Command dial have 'g' key which allow you do something(including dial next user) in dialplan AFTER hangup of first called party.

https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+cmd+Dial

```
g: When the called party hangs up, continue to execute commands 
   in the current context at the next priority.
```

Comment: I am using originate action for calling. which is something like clientSocket.Send(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Action: Originate\r\nChannel: SIP/" + fromNumber + "\r\nExten: " + strNumber + "\r\nContext: from-internal\r\nPriority: 1\r\nCallerID: " + fromNumber + "\r\n\r\n"));. Do i need to write my own dialplan? If yes then please share some more details on it because i did never write a dialplan till now.

Comment: Yes, you have write your own dialplan. Sorry, i am not gooing do your work for you. Can recommend you read book ORelly's Asterisk the future of telephony.

Comment: Sure, I am looking the book you have suggested.